# Join lines depending on the line beginning

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file that, occasionally, has split lines. The split is signaled by the fact that the line starts with a space, empty line or a nonnumeric character. E.g.

```
40403813|7|Failed|No such file or directory|1
40403816|7|Hi,
 The Conversion System could not be reached.|No such file or directory||1
40403818|7|Failed|No such file or directory|1
...
```

I'd like join the split line back with the previous line (as mentioned below):

```
40403813|7|Failed|No such file or directory|1
40403816|7|Hi, The Conversion System could not be reached.|No such file or directory||1
40403818|7|Failed|No such file or directory|1
...
```

using a Unix command like sed/awk. I'm not clear how to join a line with the preceeding one.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do anything based on the values of the strings in your fields as that could go wrong. You COULD get a wrapping line that starts with a digit, for example. Instead just print after every complete record of 5 fields:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{rec=rec $0; nf+=NF} nf>=5{print rec; nf=0; rec=""}' file
40403813|7|Failed|No such file or directory|1
40403816|7|Hi, The Conversion System could not be reached.|No such file or directory||1
40403818|7|Failed|No such file or directory|1
```

Comment: When the line is split in the last field, you will still count 5 fields.

Comment: @WalterA Good point but it LOOKS like the OP doesn't have that case. Having said that, the OPs sample input sometimes has 5 and sometimes 6 fields so idk what his real requirement is -  I'll revisit if the OP clarifies and provides better sample input/output.

Answer (score 4):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -v ORS='' 'NR>1 && /^[0-9]/{print "\n"} NF' file
```

only print newline when the current line starts with a digit, otherwise append rows (perhaps you may want to add a space to `ORS` if the line break didn't preserve the space).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    awk 'NF{printf("%s",$0 ~ /^[0-9]/ && NR>1?RS $0:$0)} END{print ""}'   Input_file
OR
    awk 'NF{printf("%s",/^[0-9]/ && NR>1?RS $0:$0)} END{print ""}'  Input_file
```

It will check if each line starts from a digit or not if yes and greater than line number 1 than it will insert a new line with-it else it will simply print it, also it will print a new line after reading the whole file, if we not mention it, it is not going to insert that at end of the file reading.

Answer (score 2):

If you only ever have the line split into two, you can use this sed command:

```
sed 'N;s/\n\([^[:digit:]]\)/\1/;P;D' infile
```

This appends the next line to the pattern space, checks if the linebreak is followed by something other than a digit, and if so, removes the linebreak, prints the pattern space up to the first linebreak, then deletes the printed part.

If a single line can be broken across more than two lines, we have to loop over the substitution:

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n\([^[:digit:]]\)/\1/;ta;P;D' infile
```

This branches from `ta` to `:a` if a substitution took place.

To use with Mac OS sed, the label and branching command must be separate from the rest of the command:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N;s/\n\([^[:digit:]]\)/\1/;ta' -e 'P;D' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

If the continuation lines always begin with a single space:

```
perl -0000 -lape 's/\n / /g' input
```

If the continuation lines can begin with an arbitrary amount of whitespace:

```
perl -0000 -lape 's/\n(\s+)/$1/g' input
```

It is probably more idiomatic to write:

```
perl -0777 -ape 's/\n / /g' input
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` when you have a file without `\r`  :

```
tr "\n" "\r" < inputfile | sed 's/\r\([^0-9]\)/\1/g' | tr '\r' '\n'
```